# c++/Lua - Load multiple lua file names into a c++ string[automatically]

Tags: c++, lua, fstream

I want to load multiple file names from a dictionary(for example "Data/lua_files") into a C++ string, without adding them manually. For example whenever I add a new file I should be able to use it when I start my program without adding any code. Currently I use Sol2.0.

Can I save all file names into a new .txt file?(with a lua script?)
Is there any way to archive that?

I checked Google but didnt find anything

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by a "dictionary" you mean a Lua table:

```
fileNames = { 
    "file1.txt",
    "file2.txt",
    "file3.txt"
}
```

Then it's as easy as `table.concat(fileNames, ",")`. It will return a string which you can then e.g. save into a global variable:

```
fileNamesString = table.concat(fileNames, ",")
```

And then use Sol to read it from the C++ side. I wonder if it's necessary to go through that extra step, though; I thought that the library supported direct table access. With that in mind, it'd be enough to just:

```
sol::lua_state lua;
// read your script file here

for (std::string const& fileName : lua["fileNames"]) {
    // do your operation
}
```

Comment: @AutobahnPolizei Oh, okay. So you want to load all lua scripts from a folder? From Lua side or C++ side? (who's gonna do the `ls` equivalent?)

Comment: Yes, into a C++ String/C++ side(?). And whenever I create a new .lua file the new file name should be added automaically.

Comment: @AutobahnPolizei Well then you're gonna need something like `Boost.Filesystem`. It's not a C++ standard feature.